# Do i have to install uWSGI Cheaper algorithms?

Tags: uwsgi

Versions i use:

uWSGI: 2.0.19.1 (64bit)

os: Linux-3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64

---

I am currently want to set up my vassal app with the uWSGI cheaper subsystem to handle the workers etc.

I decided to use the "spare2" algorithm, like in the uWSGI Doc´s explained.

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cheaper.html?highlight=spare2#spare2-cheaper-algorithm

However i get this message in my app log

```
unable to find requested cheaper algorithm, falling back to spare
```

So i looked into my uWSGI app with

`uwsgi --cheaper-algos-list`

```
*** uWSGI loaded cheaper algorithms ***
busyness
spare
backlog
manual
--- end of cheaper algorithms list ---
```

And it seems there is no "spare2" algorithm. In the Docs, Changelog of uWSGI i could not find any hint if "spare2" is maybe replaced or needed some special installment.

---

**Question:**

What happened with the "spare2" algorithm? Did i miss something in my uwsgi prerequisites? Do i have to download this as a plugin? Do i have to install uWSGI Cheaper algorithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah I ran into the same problem, debugging for hours why `spare2` was behaving exactly like `spare` would, without noticing the log line saying that `spare2` was unavailable.

Anyway, yes, the PyPI version of `uwsgi` is `2.0.x` while the documentation and github code in `master` are `2.1.x`. From what I'm reading, this difference has been around for [quite some time](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1962).

The author of `spare2` kindly backported the plugin to `2.0.x`: https://github.com/KLab/uwsgi-cheaper-spare2.

I'm inclined to use the built-in `busyness`, but then, in `2.1.x` the situation will reverse: `spare2` is built-in and `busyness` is plug-in.